# Custom Shortcut Icons Not Showing (Blank Page), Using UNC Path for an SMB Share

Tags: windows-10, shell, network-shares, icons, smb

On my Server have a custom Icon (ICO) that I created that is in the directory of a .NET / C# Application that I want to share, right along side the EXE for the Application, which has an Icon (ICO) compiled into it.

When I share the Application's root folder, via SMB Share and then go to a Client PC and create a Shortcut (LNK) to that EXE, using a UNC Target Path, my Shortcut (LNK) shows the compiled ICO.

This EXE can take Parameters, so i have a separate Shortcut (LNK) that I use that has the Parameters saved in the Target field of the Shortcut (LNK). When I try to apply my custom Icon (ICO) to this Shortcut (LNK) on a Client PC, the custom Icon (ICO) turns into a blank sheet of paper.

This makes it so I have to copy the Icon (ICO) locally and set the Shortcut (LNK) to look at the local Icon (ICO), rather than using the Icon (ICO) that resides in the network share directory, mentioned above. This method works, but is not preferred, as it makes it harder for users to manage their own shortcuts in a way that also represents the software, via its Icon (ICO), in an aesthetically-pleasing manner. (Having a blank ICO makes the software look bad.)

Is there any way to get SMB to share the Icon (ICO) properly? This happens on may clients' PCs and I really want to get it working, so I don't have to do all of this extra footwork to have a custom Icon (ICO) on the Shortcut (LNK) client-side?

I have tried redesigning the Icon (ICO) and it does follow the Windows standards, noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-icons.

Any ideas of what could be causing the custom ICO to not work over a share, when the ICO compiled in the EXE works over a share and the Custom ICO works locally?